# Slider Auto Play ReactAwesome

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a React Awesome Slider. https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-slider

I have implemented in successfully but I cannot figure out how to make it auto play every 10 seconds or so. I assume I need to use the animation hooks? It also has infinite prop but when I add it nothing happens.

```
const onAnimationStart = ({
  element,
  currentIndex,
  nextIndex,
  currentScreen,
  nextScreen,
}) => {
  /*
    ... do Something
  */
}

/* ... */

const slider = (
  <AwesomeSlider
    cssModule={styles}
    onFirstMount={onFirstMount}
    onAnimationStart={onAnimationStart}
    onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd}
  >
    <div data-src="/path/to/image-0.png" />
    <div data-src="/path/to/image-1.png" />
    <div data-src="/path/to/image-2.jpg" />
  </AwesomeSlider>
);
```

Comment: I can't say for certain, but [looking at the props there doesn't seem to be a way to make it autoplay](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-slider/blob/2a44c6a93976385ceec9df807b4103a3f0e18b10/src/core/index.js#L44-L64).

Comment: How about the infinite prop?

Comment: I think the infinite prop is for the slider to give you slide `1` again if you swipe right at the last slide.

Answer (score 0):

There is a HOC that make it autoplay. This is what you need.

```
import AwesomeSlider from 'react-awesome-slider'
import withAutoplay from 'react-awesome-slider/dist/autoplay'

const AutoplaySlider = withAutoplay(AwesomeSlider)

const Slider = () => (
<AutoplaySlider play={true}>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</AutoplaySlider>
)
```